# Tefillin at mincha on fast days

Tags: tefilin, fast-days, mincha-afternoon-prayer

At my shul (a sephardi one), I occasionally see people wearing tefillin at mincha on fast days (other than Tisha b'Av). Is this a minhag with a source, or is there some other reason why people do this?

Comment: I know that this is the minhag in the London and Amsterdam S&P's. http://www.chazzanut-esnoga.org/weekdays/weekdays.htm

Comment: I think this is common among Moroccans.

Answer (score 4):

[Rabbi Maroof](http://askrabbimaroof.blogspot.com/2006/10/tefillin-at-minha-on-fast-days.html) attributes this to the Beis Yosef (he doesn't give an exact citation).

He lists three reasons why.

1) To help reach [100 blessings for the day](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/987904/jewish/How-Many-Blessings-does-a-Jew-Say-Each-Day.htm).

2) Increased spiritual awareness on a fast day allows one to increase the amount of time in a day that Tefillin is worn.

3) Wearing Tefillin focuses concentration during prayer.

Comment: RE number 3: Shouldn't that also apply to Minchah everyday? Why would we only wear the Tefillin on a fast day?

Comment: @Salmononius2, to quote the link: "On Fast Days, we wish for our prayers to be of an especially high quality."

Comment: It's OC 46 [15char]